# What is the solution for this error in Junit 4.0? The error is "dom locators are not implemented yet"

Tags: selenium, junit

I have generated the script using Selenium IDE. But not giving me proper output.

```
 ERROR: Caught exception [Error: Dom locators are not implemented yet!]
 ERROR: Caught exception [Error: Dom locators are not implemented yet!]
```

This gets displayed instead of the element code.

I have tried xpath locator. But its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Read the error.

> `Dom locators are not implemented yet!`

That could maybe, I'm not sure, mean, that the DOM locators are not implemented yet and you need to use another locator strategy. Look at [all available locator strategies](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#locators) and pick one. The often used ones are `id`, `name`, `css`, `xpath`, ideally in this order (from weakest to strongest, but also from fastest to slowest).

By the way, Selenium RC has been oficially deprecated two years ago in favor of the new and shiny Selenium WebDriver. If you want to use something that's actually supported and developed, export your scripts to WebDriver.

Comment: I don't think them said anything about Selenium RC? I exported for WebDriver and got the same happening...

Comment: @SanderVerhagen Well. To be honest, I didn't even think about WebDriver, because WebDriver itself doesn't support DOM locating. Selenium RC does. But IDE, as it seems, does not.

Comment: It seems IDE supports them, but when exporting there is nothing to convert it to. Like the original poster might have experienced, it gave me a "what the heck" moment, since it felt like a big gap when exporting IDE to Java.